# Modify Chart properties in Access report via VBA (error 2771)

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts, ms-access-2010

I am building an Access report (2010 version), and would like to be able to customize it based on the user's selections  on a form. When I run it, I get error 2771: The bound or unbound object frame you tried to edit does not contain an OLE object.

This is the code to pass the parameter:

```
Private Sub Command120_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rpt_EODGraph", View:=acViewPreview, _
      OpenArgs:=Me!Text0.Value
End Sub
```

This is the code to open the report.

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim ch As Chart
    Set ch = Me.Graph3.Object.Application.Chart 'This line generates the error
    ch.ChartTitle.text = OpenArgs
End Sub
```

I've found at least one person saying that this is not actually possible to do on a report. (http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=177778&page=2 Note that this is page 2 of a 2 page forum discussion...) Can anyone corroborate or refute?

Comment: Try putting your code in the 'Activate' event rather than the 'Open' event. 'Open' is called BEFORE satisfying the recordsource.

Comment: Thanks Wayne, but no dice. It opens in print preview mode (my bad for choosing the wrong acView option), and give the same error when I change to report view. After changing the code to acViewReport, I'm getting the same error on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the Report has to have some kind of focus before OLE objects are accessible.
It is enough if you click on it or set the focus to something:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim ch As Object
    Me.RandomButton.SetFocus
    Set ch = Me.Diagramm11.Object
    ch.ChartTitle.Text = "Hello"    
End Sub
```

This works. I just set a button on the report that gets the focus. Perhaps you find something more elegant ;)