# How can I change the Chart Title in an Access report with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, charts

I have an Access Report with a chart and I want to change the title of the chart when the report is opened (preview or print).
I found the following code:

```
Dim g As Graph.Chart
Set g = Me!Graph0.Object
With g
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Test"
End With
```

But I don't know with which event I should run this code. I tried Report_Open and other events but it never changes the title.

Comment: Is there such a thing like report_activate in access VBA?  I'm only assuming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[Modify Chart properties in Access report via VBA (error 2771)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113380/modify-chart-properties-in-access-report-via-vba-error-2771)

First I copied the chart from a report to a form and tested the code to change the title. That worked.
Then I tried to run the code with the open or load event in the report and I always received an error. I googled that error and found the article above and that was the solution.
I just added a button to the report and added the line

```
Me.Command1.SetFocus
```

at the beginning of my code.
Now I can run the code from Report_Load() or Report_Open(). It works for both.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your code works, but to trigger an event on opening a report you need to put the code into the `Report.Load` event.

Check out msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197739.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnActivate event if using a Form.